# How to activate Speech Recognition with a word in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

currently I'm working on a Virtual Assistant project
wherein, it takes voice commands and executes it.

Now, I have named him as 'MARK'

Now I have given this code the access to my mic

here is the code.....

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def takeCommand():
    # It is the recognizer
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    # Kept the microphone as source
    with sr.Microphone() as source: # It should keep listening but only when I say 'Mark'
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold=1
        audio = r.listen(source)    
    try:
        print("Reconizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
        print(f"You said : {query}\n")
    except Exception as error:
        # print(error)
        print('Say that again please')
```

Over here in this function, he hears everything and then converts it into text

but I don't want him to always be listening to me, I mean, He should listen, but only respond when I say 'MARK'

So for this purpose, I altered the code like this....

```
def listen_to_navdeep():
    # It is the recognizer
    r=sr.Recognizer()
    # Kept the microphone as source
    with sr.Microphone() as source: # It should keep listening but only when I say 'Mark'
        r.pause_threshold=1
        audio = r.listen(source)    
    while True:
        try:
            query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="en-in")
            query=query.lower()
            if "mark" in query:
                return query
                break
            else:
                pass
        except:
            pass

# Now I am outside the function....

while True:
    command=listen_to_navdeep
    # Some process runs over here.....
```

Now even though I did it, there would be some time-mishappenings

So what I wanted to do is that he should be actively listening the voice but still should respond (and also not print the exception that there wasn't any speech)or convert it to text and run some process, in fact the moment I tell "Mark" then he should start recording the voice and then process it to text and do whatever is assigned (Please don't worry above the tasks which it will be doing)

Another good example to explain my problem is how "Alexa" works. Alexa keeps on listening everything in the home or surroundings, but doesn't react. She only react whenever I we say 'Alexa'. That's what I want over here....in my AI assistant.

Please tell me how to achieve it....

Looking forward for help....

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing the following:

```
wake_word = "Mark"

while True:
    print("Listening")
    text = take_command()

    if text.count(wake_word) > 0:
        talk("I am ready")
        text = take_command()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a speak function for him to speak and you will have to import pyttsx3 module.
Install it by running this command in the terminal.

```
pip install pyttsx3
```

The speak function works somewhat like this

```
speak("Thank Me Later For this and upvote")
```

Comment: Hi Messi,I appreciate your prompt response

but That answer doesn't answer my question I already know about pyttsx3 and I use it heavily Sorry if I wasn't able to give a good explaination in my question

Another thing is that there isn't any speak function in pyttsx3 module...